# When merging two images CISourceOverCompositing losing alpha for watermark

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage

I am merging two images using CIImage filter CISourceOverCompositing
issue is it is losing alpha/opacity of watermark/foreground image if its applied opacity is less than one.
I applied alpha value like this

```
  CGFloat rgba[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, alphaVal};

  CIFilter *colorMatrix = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
```

I think issue is I need to change alpha from CIImage through some calculation as CIImage working space is not same as UIImage.

want these type of calculation for CIImage rgbs

[Core Image filter CISourceOverCompositing not appearing as expected with alpha overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969223/core-image-filter-cisourceovercompositing-not-appearing-as-expected-with-alpha-o)